# date to be converted to UK date format with preserving 0's

Tags: c#

I want my date to be converted to UK date format. 
so example if its 26/2/2016 then it should be converted to 26/02/2016.
if its a 2/13/2016 then it should be converted to 13/02/2016.
The end result should be UK format with preserving 0 in day and month.

**Code**

```
string cellvalue; 
string oData = "2/13/2016"; 

if (DateTime.TryParse((string)oData, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, styles, out dt)) 
{ 
    cellvalue = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
    Console.WriteLine(cellvalue + "go to hell"); 
} 
else 
{ 
    cellvalue = oData.ToString(); 
    Console.WriteLine(cellvalue + "go to bokaro"); 
}
```

Comment: Do you have a string or datetime object

Comment: What did you try so far? What value do you start with? DateTime? string?

Comment: But the above doesnot work for 26/2/2016. It gives me 26/2/2016

Answer (score 0):

Easyyy:

```
CultureInfo enGB = new CultureInfo("en-GB"); 
string oData = "2/13/2016"; 
DateTime dateValue;

// Parse date with no style flags.
dateString = "13/02/2016";
DateTime.TryParseExact(oData, "g", enGB, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want resulting date to be in default UK format i.e. `dd/MM/yyyy` no matter if input date string is in `MM/dd/yyyy` or `dd/MM/yyyy`, former being default format for US dates.

You were close in the code you have already tried. Additionally you need to one thing - if input is in US format, parse it as `DateTime` using US culture, and then simply transform to UK.

```
var UKCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
var USCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime dt;
string cellvalue; 

string oData = "13/2/2016"; 

// First try parsing to UK format
if (!DateTime.TryParse(oData, UKCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt)) 
{ 
    // If fails, then try US format
    DateTime.TryParse(oData, USCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
}

// Once you have DateTime instance, you can do anything. Parsing is over.
cellvalue = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
Console.Write(cellvalue);
```

So now this gives final value as `13/02/2016` for both `2/13/2016` and `13/2/2016` inputs.